# Unset specific property of JSON in PHP

Tags: php, json

**JSON**

```
{
 "pages":{
   "index.php":{
      "status":"enabled",
      "theme":"dark",
      "identifier":"KMS"
  },
   "google.php":{
      "status":"enabled",
      "theme":"dark",
      "identifier":"KMS"
  },
   "doodle.php":{
      "status":"disabled",
      "theme":"light",
      "identifier":"transact"
   }
 }
}
```

In my PHP code I write

```
$jsona = file_get_contents("../pages.json");
$jsonb = json_decode($jsona,true);  
$data = $jsonb['pages'];
```

Now if I want to delete the property `"index.php"` I write `unset($data["index.php"]` and then I write

```
file_put_contents("../pages.json",json_encode($data));
```

Though after going to my JSON file it deletes `"pages"`

**actual outcome**

```
{"google.php":{"status":"enabled","theme":"dark","identifier":"KMS"},"doodle.php":{"status":"disabled","theme":"light","identifier":"transact"}}
```

I need to just unset a specific child property of pages. Such as `"google.php"` or `"doodle.php"`. I checked what is being posted as `$data[$page]` and it is the specific element. So why is it unsetting `pages` and leaving the rest of the properties?

Comment: It's not unsetting pages, you're just not serializing that part... Try `json_encode(array("pages"=>$data))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't set `$data` to `$jsonb['pages']`. That's specifically setting your `$data` variable to a sub-section of your overall object.

Just use `unset($jsonb['pages']['index.php'])`.

Comment: Ok I'll try that out.

Comment: Alrighty so that worked. Why did setting `$data = $jsonb['pages']` mess it up?

Comment: Because you were "cropping" away the outer-most object. If I have `x = { a: 'b'}`, and use `y = x['a']`, `y` has lost the outer-most object, and is now just the string `'b'`.

Comment: Ah ok. Well that explains it :D Thanks Meagar!